# Загрузить данные из JSON файлов

Tags: python, json, файлы

Есть папка, а в ней произвольное количество JSON файлов с произвольными именами. Нужно считать по-очереди каждый из них и добавить их содержимое в один список.

Пытался реализовать так:

```
files = os.listdir(path)
filesCount = len(files) # кол-во файлов в папке
filesList = []
for num in range(filesCount):
    file = open(path, "r", encoding="utf-8") # открыть файл с произвольным именем
    temp = json.load(file)
    filesList.append(temp)
    file.close()
```

Здесь нужно открыть файл с произвольным именем.

Как открыть все файлы в цикле, зная только их количество?

Comment: А почему «зная только их количество», когда у вас в переменной `files` прекрасно лежат имена всех файлов?

Comment: Да, точно, спасибо большое)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
try:
    from pathlib import Path       # Python 3.x
except ImportError:
    from pathlib2 import Path      # Python 2.x  (pip install pathlib2)

res = [json.loads(file.read_text(encoding="utf-8"))
       for file in Path(path).glob('*.json')]
```

Comment: зачем нужен pathlib если дергаем его зависимость glob из стандартных либ?

Comment: @eri, причин несколько - при помощи `pathlib` можно искать и в  поддиректориях `.glob('**/*.json')` и код выглядит короче и красивее (это мое субъективное мнение)

Comment: glob.glob() тоже ищет в **, без Path(path) не так громоздко. А кстати ещё вопрос к примеру Вашему: файл будет закрыт в итераторе этом?

Comment: @eri, [судя по всему закрытие файла при удалении последней ссылки на него зависит от реализации и не гарантированно спеками языка](https://askubuntu.com/a/701536), поэтому безопаснее будет использовать `..read_text()`, который явно закрывает файл после чтения (исправил в ответе)

Answer (score 0):

Можно пройтись в цикле по списку files:

```
files = os.listdir(path)
filesCount = len(files) # кол-во файлов в папке
filesList = []
for num in range(filesCount):
    file = open(path + str(files[num]), "r", encoding="utf-8")
    temp = json.load(file)
    filesList.append(temp)
    file.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

А можно по маске через `glob`:

```
import glob, json
filesList = []
for filename in glob.glob('somedir/*.json'):
    with open(filename, "r", encoding="utf-8") as file:
       filesList.append(json.load(file))
```

Маска работает также как у команды `ls` (?,*,** и тд).